# Array of objects condensed into array of unique objects with nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, chart.js

I have the arr data in MongoDB and need to condense the documents into one so that I can display the data in chartjs.

```
arr = [
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be2d",
        "awaySpread": "3.0",
        "homeSpread": "-3.0",
        "homeTeam": "Tennessee Titans",
        "awayId": "4529605_261_sp",
        "awayTeam": "Indianapolis Colts",
        "homeId": "4529605_262_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00",
        "createdDate": "2019-09-13T13:00:06.527Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be31",
        "awaySpread": "-19.5",
        "homeSpread": "19.5",
        "homeTeam": "Miami Dolphins",
        "awayId": "4529609_269_sp",
        "awayTeam": "New England Patriots",
        "homeId": "4529609_270_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00",
        "createdDate": "2019-09-13T13:00:06.527Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be2d",
        "awaySpread": "2.5",
        "homeSpread": "-2.5",
        "homeTeam": "Tennessee Titans",
        "awayId": "4529605_261_sp",
        "awayTeam": "Indianapolis Colts",
        "homeId": "4529605_262_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00",
        "createdDate": "2019-09-13T13:30:06.527Z"
    }
]
```

Looking to get it into:

```
newarr = [
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be2d",
        "awaySpread": "3.0",
        "homeSpread": "-3.0",
        "homeTeam": "Tennessee Titans",
        "awayId": "4529605_261_sp",
        "awayTeam": "Indianapolis Colts",
        "homeId": "4529605_262_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00",
        "createdDate": "2019-09-13T13:00:06.527Z",
        "lines": {
           "spread": ["3.0","2.5"],
           "dates: : ["2019-09-13T13:00:06.527Z","2019-09-13T13:30:06.527Z"]
         },

    },
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be31",
        "awaySpread": "-19.5",
        "homeSpread": "19.5",
        "homeTeam": "Miami Dolphins",
        "awayId": "4529609_269_sp",
        "awayTeam": "New England Patriots",
        "homeId": "4529609_270_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00"
        "createdDate": "2019-09-13T13:00:06.527Z",
        "lines": {
           "spread": ["-19.5"],
           "dates: : ["2019-09-13T13:00:06.527Z"]
         },
    }
]
```

I'm able use filter to only return unique objects based on awayId, but I'm not sure using filter will allow me to push lines with spreads and dates.

Comment: Where do the `createdDate`s come from?

Comment: Just search for "group array of objects by property" on SO

Comment: createdDate is set when the record is created in the DB

Comment: And why is it missing in the input `arr`?

Comment: sorry, updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

Im building an object where the id is the key and the value is the object.
When I already have the id inside (The second time i meet the same id), i push to lines the relevant values.

Finally i console log the values of the object which is your desired output.

```
arr = [
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be2d",
        "awaySpread": "3.0",
        "homeSpread": "-3.0",
        "homeTeam": "Tennessee Titans",
        "awayId": "4529605_261_sp",
        "awayTeam": "Indianapolis Colts",
        "homeId": "4529605_262_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be31",
        "awaySpread": "-19.5",
        "homeSpread": "19.5",
        "homeTeam": "Miami Dolphins",
        "awayId": "4529609_269_sp",
        "awayTeam": "New England Patriots",
        "homeId": "4529609_270_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d7baef782e09dc7f6b5be2d",
        "awaySpread": "2.5",
        "homeSpread": "-2.5",
        "homeTeam": "Tennessee Titans",
        "awayId": "4529605_261_sp",
        "awayTeam": "Indianapolis Colts",
        "homeId": "4529605_262_sp",
        "eventDate": "2019-09-15 13:00:00"
    }
]

const newArr = arr.reduce((result, itr) => {
  if (result[itr.awayId]) {
    result[itr.awayId].lines.spread.push(itr.awaySpread)
    result[itr.awayId].lines.dates.push(itr.eventDate)
  } else {
    result[itr.awayId] = { ...itr, lines: { spread: [itr.awaySpread], dates: [itr.eventDate] }}
  }
  return result
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(newArr))
```

Comment: Thanks but this only nests the spread and dates, doesn't condense by unique awayId

Comment: The groupBy is according to the `_id` or `awayId`?

Comment: awayId, I realized that after i commented. Thanks!

Comment: You can control it :) GL